# How does this compile?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-programming, comparator

I'm writing a function that takes a list of keyExtractor functions to produce a Comparator (imagine we had an object with many many properties and wanted to be able to arbitrarily compare by a large number of properties in any order).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Test {
    public static <T, S extends Comparable<S>> Comparator<T> parseKeysAscending(List<Function<T, S>> keyExtractors) {
        if (keyExtractors.isEmpty()) {
            return (a, b) -> 0;
        } else {
            Function<T, S> firstSortKey = keyExtractors.get(0);
            List<Function<T, S>> restOfSortKeys = keyExtractors.subList(1, keyExtractors.size());
            return Comparator.comparing(firstSortKey).thenComparing(parseKeysAscending(restOfSortKeys));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Extractor<Data, ?>> extractors = new ArrayList<>();
        extractors.add(new Extractor<>(Data::getA));
        extractors.add(new Extractor<>(Data::getB));

        Comparator<Data> test = parseKeysAscending(
                extractors.stream()
                        .map(e -> e)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

}


class Extractor<T, S extends Comparable<S>> implements Function<T, S> {
    private final Function<T, S> extractor;

    Extractor(Function<T, S> extractor) {
        this.extractor = extractor;
    }

    @Override
    public S apply(T t) {
        return extractor.apply(t);
    }
}

class Data {
    private final Integer a;
    private final Integer b;

    private Data(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

There are three main points of confusion for me:

1). If I don't define the Extractor class, this will not compile. I cannot directly have Functions or some sort of functional interface.

2). If I remove the identity function mapping line ".map(e -> e)", this will not type check.

3). My IDE says my function is accepting a List of Functions of the type Data -> ? which doesn't comply with the bounds of the parseKeysAscending function.

Comment: There *does* seem to be some wonky stuff going on here.  Question worth asking to me, since my IDE also optimizes out the mapping but then immediately refuses to compile.  What version of Java are you using?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375454/why-is-this-a-good-question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me without the `Extractor` class and also without calling `map(e -> e)` in the stream pipeline. Actually, streaming the list of extractors isn't needed at all if you use the correct generic types.

As to why your code doesn't work, I'm not completely sure. Generics is a tough and flaky aspect of Java... All I did was adjusting the signature of the `parseKeysAscending` method, so that it conforms to what [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) actually expects.

Here's the `parseKeysAscending` method:

```
public static <T, S extends Comparable<? super S>> Comparator<T> parseKeysAscending(
        List<Function<? super T, ? extends S>> keyExtractors) {

    if (keyExtractors.isEmpty()) {
        return (a, b) -> 0;
    } else {

        Function<? super T, ? extends S> firstSortKey = keyExtractors.get(0);
        List<Function<? super T, ? extends S>> restOfSortKeys = 
            keyExtractors.subList(1, keyExtractors.size());

        return Comparator.<T, S>comparing(firstSortKey)
            .thenComparing(parseKeysAscending(restOfSortKeys));
    }
}
```

And here's a demo with the call:

```
List<Function<? super Data, ? extends Comparable>> extractors = new ArrayList<>();
extractors.add(Data::getA);
extractors.add(Data::getB);

Comparator<Data> test = parseKeysAscending(extractors);

List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new Data(1, "z"),
    new Data(2, "b"),
    new Data(1, "a")));

System.out.println(data); // [[1, 'z'], [2, 'b'], [1, 'a']]

data.sort(test);

System.out.println(data); // [[1, 'a'], [1, 'z'], [2, 'b']]
```

The only way to make the code compile without warnings was to declare the list of functions as `List<Function<Data, Integer>>`. But this works only with getters that return `Integer`. I'm assuming that you might want to compare any mix of `Comparable`s, i.e. the code above works with the following `Data` class:

```
public class Data {
    private final Integer a;
    private final String b;

    private Data(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + a + ", '" + b + "']";
    }
}
```

Here's the [demo](https://ideone.com/de7EP5).

**EDIT:** Note that with Java 8, the last line of the `parseKeysAscending` method can be:

```
return Comparator.comparing(firstSortKey)
        .thenComparing(parseKeysAscending(restOfSortKeys));
```

While for newer versions of Java, you must provide explicit generic types:

```
return Comparator.<T, S>comparing(firstSortKey)
        .thenComparing(parseKeysAscending(restOfSortKeys));
```

Comment: I still don't understand where the problem was or is (it compiled with java-11 that I have and use), but as a side note I think that method can be shorten to `public static <T, S extends Comparable<S>> Comparator<T> parseKeysAscending(List<Function<T, S>> keyExtractors) {
        return keyExtractors.stream()
                .collect(Collector.of(
                        () -> (Comparator<T>) (x, y) -> 0,
                        Comparator::thenComparing,
                        Comparator::thenComparing));
    }`

Comment: Two interesting observations for your code Federico:
1). This doesn't work for me if I remove the stream in the call
2). I am getting a "cannot resolve method" in the recursive call yet it still successfully runs.

Comment: This looks like what I am going for. I think this is also a great example for me to understand contravariance/covariance in Java through the wildcard type.

This may be IDE specific, but using the method as written gives me an unchecked method exception. If I use the intermediate "extractor" class as before, this warning goes away.

Also, doesn't this still mean our method is accepting some type "S extends Comparable<? super S>"? I don't think there should be any way to call this with data that has both a string and integer field without getting the unchecked warning.

Comment: @BillytheKid Honestly, I'm not getting that exception/compilation error, so I cannot tell. Usually, Eclipse compiler is known to have issues with type inference (i.e. covariance/contravariance, generic types. lambdas and method references all mixed together). As to the unchecked warning, I don't think there's a way to get rid of it.

Comment: I'm  using Intellij, but I think the issue is really in the type definition:
public static <T, S extends Comparable<? super S>> Comparator<T> parseKeysAscending(List<Function<? super T, ? extends S>> keyExtractors)

We actually don't care at all about the type S at all, we just care that we can compare it. So we would need a way to represent a type which is any comparable object which I believe would need be ? extends Comparable<?>

Comment: @BillytheKid I tried that in ideone.com and it didn't compile because `Comparator.thenComparing` needs an argument of type `Function<T, S extends Comparable<? super S>>`, which doesn't match to `Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>`.

Comment: When trying various versions of compilers, javac 8 is the only one that accepts this variant. Newer versions reject the program. Eclipse (ecj) has been rejecting the program in all versions since Java 8 was released. Ergo, some of the confusion seems to result from a bug in javac, that was fixed in 9.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I've edited my answer as per your comment, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 8):

After Federico corrected me (thank you!) this is a single method you could do it with:

```
public static <T, S extends Comparable<? super S>> Comparator<T> test(List<Function<T, S>> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .reduce((x, y) -> 0,
                    Comparator::thenComparing,
                    Comparator::thenComparing);
}
```

And usage would be:

```
// I still don't know how to avoid this raw type here
List<Function<Data, Comparable>> extractors = new ArrayList<>();
extractors.add(Data::getA); // getA returns an Integer
extractors.add(Data::getB); // getB returns a String

listOfSomeDatas.sort(test(extractors));
```

Comment: Very nice, this does make sense as the original recursive function follows a pretty standard fold-like pattern.

Comment: I still like `list.stream().map(Comparator::comparing).reduce(Comparator::thenComparing).orElse((Comparator<T>) (a, b) -> 0)` more than this, but +1 for keeping all this generics nightmare simple.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. If I don't define the `Extractor` class, this will not compile. I cannot directly have `Function`s or some sort of functional interface.

No, you can. You can define any `Function<X, Y>` by a lambda, or method reference, or anonymous class.

```
List<Function<Data, Integer>> extractors = List.of(Data::getA, Data::getB);
```

> 2. If I remove the identity function mapping line `.map(e -> e)`, this will not type check.

It still will, but the result may not be suitable for the method. You can always define generic parameters explicitly to make sure that everything goes as you expect.

```
extractors.<Function<Data, Integer>>stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But there is no need for that here:

```
Comparator<Data> test = parseKeysAscending(extractors);
```

> 3. My IDE says my function is accepting a `List` of `Function`s of the type `Data, ?` which doesn't comply with the bounds of the `parseKeysAscending` function.

Yes, it should. You are passing a `List<Extractor<Data, ?>>` and the compiler can't understand the `?` part. It may or may not be a `Comparable` while your method clearly requires `S extends Comparable<S>`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding original code in the question: you can remove `Extractor` and use a raw `Comparable`:

```
List<Function<Data, Comparable>> extractors = new ArrayList<>();

extractors.add(Data::getA);
extractors.add(Data::getB);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Comparator<Data> test = parseKeysAscending(extractors);
```

P.S. Yet I don't see how to get rid of the raw type here...